# Short, simple command to create a group if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: command-line, users, group

What is the cleanest way to modify this command in bash to only run if the group does not exist?

```
groupadd somegroupname
```

A one-liner would be best.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
getent group somegroupname || groupadd somegroupname
```

Comment: Thanks. In case it helps anyone, this slight modification avoids printing output from the first command: `[ $(getent group somegroupname) ] || groupadd somegroupname`

Comment: Or just redirect it's output to /dev/null

Answer (score 15):

With force it exits successfully if the group already exists, and cancels -g if the GID is already used.

```
groupadd -f somegroupname
```