# Unable to add entry in /etc/group

Tags: linux, users, group

Ran below commands to create a group

```
[root@u87 ~] # groupadd -g 2441 somegroup
groupadd: group 'somegroup' already exists
[root@u87 ~]# cat /etc/group | grep somegroup
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]# 
[root@u87 ~]# cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

---

How do I understand this error?

Comment: What does `getent group somegroup` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt output is `somegroup:*:2441:someuser`. Does local groupname always sit in `/etc/group`?

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145351/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups (and other user information) can be defined in places other than `/etc/group`; *e.g.* LDAP. The sources of information are configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

To retrieve information from whatever sources *are* used, use `getent`:

```
getent group somegroup
```

You can use this [to check the existence of a group before trying to add it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145351/86440):

```
getent group somegroup || groupadd -g 2441 somegroup
```

Comment: how to retrieve information of  `someuser` from LDAP? `getent user`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `getent user someuser` does not work. I would like to know the uid